# Maven profile not deploying to correct tomcat using maven-tomcat-plugin

Tags: maven, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

So my Maven doesn't want to pickup the right profile, doesn't matter how I tell it:

`mvn -Denv=dev tomcat7:deploy-only` or `mvn -P dev -Denv=dev tomcat7:deploy-only`

I have two servers configured on my `settings.xml` and have my configuration below pointing to the correct ones.

Using `mvn -X` it seems that Maven is always picking up the last server in order it appears on the file, which means it's picking up the `prod` server.

Any clues anyone? Thank you!

Here's my `<profiles>`:

```
<profiles>
<profile>
  <id>dev</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>env</name>
      <value>dev</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
        <configuration>
          <server>dev</server>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
          <username>tomcat</username>
          <password>tomcat</password>
          <path>/</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>prod</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>env</name>
      <value>prod</value>
    </property>
    <jdk>1.6</jdk>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
        <configuration>
          <server>prod</server>
          <url>http://remote/manager/text</url>
          <username>usr</username>
          <password>pwd</password>
          <path>/</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Ok, so I managed to get it working after some changes. I moved the url, server, username and password to properties **inside** the profile and moved the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` to the main `<build>` on the `pom.xml`, passing the properties as parameters. However, I can only set the properties if I add the `-D` parameter to the `mvn` command. Is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: could you please post your updated config with "url, server, username and password to properties inside the profile and moved the tomcat7-maven-plugin to the main <build> on the pom.xml, passing the properties as parameters". I am trying to do the same config with profiles setting just properties for various deploy configurations and just one deploy plugin and I am stuck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra "activation" of `<jdk>1.6</jdk>` in your prod profile. Activations are an "or", not an "and". I'm guessing you're running maven with jdk6, and so prod is always active. Being the last one in the pom, its settings will win--a general rule in maven.